# How to add google map in ionic card?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I tried to add google map in ionic card, but the map doesn't show up. The map does show up if it is not in the ion-card. Can you help?

HTML:

```
</ion-content>
  <ion-card class="transparent-card">
    <div #map id="map"></div>
  </ion-card> 
</ion-content>
```

SCSS:

```
ion-card {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}

.card-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 36%;
  font-size: 2.0em;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.card-subtitle {
  font-size: 1.0em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 52%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.transparent-card{
    background-color: transparent;
}

#map{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try this!.

```
<ion-card class="transparent-card">
    <div #map id="gmap" style="height:100px;"></div>
</ion-card>

.transparent-card{
        background-color: transparent;
 }
```